# J1939 address claim: if primary source address can not be claimed, do I need a separate DBC file for secondary source address?

Tags: can

I read the J1939-81 document and the following regarding the address claim procedure:

[sae-j1939-address-claim-procedure](https://copperhilltech.com/blog/sae-j1939-address-claim-procedure-sae-j193981-network-management/#:%7E:text=In%20order%20to%20provide%20a,another%20ECU%20in%20the%20network)

[j1939-introduction](https://www.kvaser.com/about-can/higher-layer-protocols/j1939-introduction/#:%7E:text=The%20RTR%20bit%20(remote%20request,structured%20in%20the%20following%20way.&text=Table%201%3A%20Structure%20of%20a,priority%20during%20the%20arbitration%20process)

[sae-j1939-address-management-messages](https://copperhilltech.com/blog/sae-j1939-address-management-messages-address-claim-pgns/)

If arbitrary address is capable, the device can select an address from the range 128-247 (inclusive).

My plan is the use the source address (primary) when I generate the DBC file. If the secondary source address has to be used, do I need a secondary DBC file?

Or:

Should I create the DBC file with a null address and should I set CAN filters to receive (so when sending CAN messages, generate the can_id based on the source address)?

I heard from someone else that we should be able to set the source address as we want, and the DBC file does not have to be changed. From Wireshark he set the source address and he was able to see the messages coming. I don’t have evidence showing this.

What is the correct way to do this?

Edit: I think that someone was correct. Because he sees **RAW data** (DBC file is not needed in the wireshark). But when we have a dedicated DBC file we need to decode data based on the DBC_ID. When Source address is changed DBC_ID changes